# def a variable after binding *ns* to something else

Tags: clojure

I'm unclear why in the following code snippet, foo is being defined in the "user" namespace, and not the one I've bound to *ns* in the binding closure.  Can someone explain what I'm missing?

```
$ clj
Clojure 1.4.0

user=> (let [nspace (create-ns (gensym "sandbox"))]
            (binding [*ns* nspace]
                     (print (ns-name *ns*))
                     (def foo 6)))
sandbox3#'user/foo

user=> foo
6

user=> (in-ns 'sandbox3)
#

sandbox3=> foo
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0)

sandbox3=> (def bar 7)
#'sandbox3/bar

sandbox3=> bar
7

sandbox3/user=> (in-ns 'user)
#

user=> foo
6

user=> bar
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: bar in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use eval:

```
   (let [nspace (create-ns (gensym "sandbox"))]
            (binding [*ns* nspace]
                     (print (ns-name *ns*))
                     (eval '(def foo 6))))
```

`eval` pays attention to `*ns*`, but most of Clojure does not.

EDIT: Yes, I just suggested that a person use eval :p

For context, I've been corresponding with op and he doesn't want a real sandbox as he trusts the code going into his system, he simply needed a way to evaluate inputted code inside of different namespaces!

So, if you're a newbie with this question and you're not sethwm, please refer to Marczyk's answer. This solution is very specific to the OP's use case and not a generally good way to do much of anything.

Comment: Augh, no! If you absolutely must define vars in another namespace (and you probably don't), use `intern`. There's no excuse for using `eval` here.

Answer (score 6):

The namespace in which `def` will create a Var is determined at compile time. The binding is not in effect then (`binding` introduces runtime bindings).

`def` should only be used at top level or inside something like a top-level `let` form. The further one drifts away from a simple top-level `def`, the greater the care that one should exercise. For example `binding` is certainly similar to a top-level `let` in many ways and the value part of a `def` expression will be evaluated with the expected thread-local bindings in place:

```
user=> (let [nspace (create-ns (gensym "foo"))]
         (binding [*ns* nspace]
           (def foo *ns*)))
#'user/foo
user=> foo
#<Namespace foo3>
```

The fashion in which the Var is created in the first place is, however, completely unaffected by the runtime state when execution reaches the `def` form.

To create Vars dynamically, use `intern` -- it's a regular function with completely predictable behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Re: intern v def, I agree.  However I'm going to be interpreting other people's code within the binding, and cannot control if they use def v intern.  I'm making a poor man's sandbox.

Comment: Amusingly, he and I had actually been corresponding via email prior to this question. His use case is legitimate, I promise. :P

Comment: @Rayne - On your conscience be it. :-P sethwm - Well, Rayne is certainly the person to be in touch with in that case. Out of curiosity, why not use / adapt [clojail](https://github.com/Raynes/clojail)?

Comment: @MichałMarczyk He doesn't actually need a sandbox -- he trusts the code that will be evaluated. He simply needed evaluation infrastructure.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk That said, I've edited my answer to direct newbies to your answer as mine is clearly useful for his specific use case and not a very good idea for much of anything else.